# Indexof Javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically i have a string(sentence) and an array of strings(word), I am trying to compare my string or sentence to each string in my array. If it finds any string from the array in the string or sentence it should return true and do something with it. I am looking for a faster and better way to do something like this in javaScript. Below is an example of a code i have written

```
function search() {
    var sentence = "you are a good and amazing friend, you are also fast"
    var words = ["crazy", "lovely", "good", "amazing", "beautiful", "ugly", "fast"];

    //validity 
    var yes = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];

        if (sentence.indexOf(word) != -1) {
            yes = true;
            console.log(word + " found in " + sentence)
        } else {
            yes = false;
            console.log(word + " wasnt found in " + sentence)
        }
    }

    function validity() {
        if (yes == true) {
            alert(word + "thank you, you are a good friend")
        } else {
            alert(word + "thank you")
        }
    }

    validity();
}

search();
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you need someone to look at your code and optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var sentence = 'you are a good and amazing friend, you are also fast';
var words = ["crazy", "lovely", "good", "amazing", "beautiful", "ugly", "fast"];

var isValid = words.some(function(w) {
    return sentence.indexOf(w) > -1;
});

console.log(isValid); // true
```

In ES6 you can use arrow functions to make this code even more shorter:

```
let isValid = words.some(w => ~sentence.indexOf(w));
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var sentence = "you are a good and amazing friend, you are also fast";
var words = ["crazy", "lovely", "good", "amazing", "beautiful", "ugly", "fast"];

function check(item){
return sentence.search(item) > -1;
}

new_array = words.filter(check);
```

["good", "amazing", "fast"]

```
//do something with new_array that contains your matches
```